# custom colors in bing maps?

Tags: rendering, bing-maps

I was looking at  http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/26295161/ns/weather/  and noticed that the flash map is provided by bing and have a custom color scheme. I have a similar need to show maps with a black & white colortheme, is it possible using their api or have they made custom tiles ?  (doesnt seem feasible to provide tiles for alls maps on all levels :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not wedded to Bing maps, you could look into [Mapbox](http://www.mapbox.com), which provide maps based on [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) in any style that you desire.

Comment: Thanks! Havent seen cloudmade before seems like an interesting alternative, I'll check out the api

Comment: It looks like the link is outdated. The site is changed enough that it is not immediately clear how the new site relates to this question.

Comment: @Jeff, thanks. I've updated the answer to refer to Mapbox, as CloudMade don't appear to provide that service anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This question is still not answered and even if it's kind of old, I think it matters. 
In fact, they're not using different tiles or a custom tile scheme. You can see those in the network inspection tool.

Since they're inside a Flash application, they can easily change the color of the image using filter on image (ColorMatrixFilter) and changing dynamically on the client side the rendered colors.

Answer (score 1):

Well now some years later you can: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt823636.aspx :-)

(I got here by looking for some sample styles and thought I add the link for anybody else finding this question)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a custom tile skinner is that you need: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2009/11/27/bing-maps-custom-tile-skinner/

In this example, the author changes the color of roads using ColorMatrix and ColorMap:

```
The two key methods used to transform the colors 
consist of using ColorMatrix or a ColorMap. By 
using  a color matrix all the colors on the tile 
can be changed within a couple lines of code. Using 
a ColorMap allows you to change one color at a 
time. This is useful if you only want to change a 
few colors on the map.
```